# How to alter a form validation error message for individual form fields in Drupal 8

Tags: content-management-system, drupal-8, drupal-hooks

I tried using https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2016-12-14/drupal-8-custom-forms-inline-errors and form_set_error methods but could not get to a conclusion .

I want to alter the error message for validation fields for a custom module  for poll.
Even after a couple of methods , The default error message is only displayed .

Kindly suggest some way .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.